# What does the matrix mean in matrix models?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, partition-function, matrix-elements, matrix-model

I'm learning what a matrix model means, for example, in Yang–Mills matrix models, IKKT matrix model and BFSS matrix model. I have consulted a large amount of information but still not sure what the matrix mean.

All the references give the Lagrangian directly by
$$
L=\frac{1}{2g}\{{tr\dot{X^{^{i}}}}\dot{X^{^{i}}}+2\theta^{T}\dot{\theta}+\frac{1}{2}tr[X^{i},X^{j}]^{2}-2\theta^{T}\gamma_{i}[\theta,X^{i}]\}
$$
And mention that $X^{{i}}$ is Hermitian $N\times N$ matrix. But I'm wondering what the **element** in $X$ is?

An simple instance is if we have oscillators, and the Hamiltonian is
$$
H=trP^{2}+trX^{2}+\frac{g}{N}trX^{4}.
$$
How can I know what the {${X_{ij}}$} looks like?

(I'm also confused that if the dimension $N$ means there is $N$ oscillators, and the number of matrix means the dimension of spacetime. They are so complicated for me.)

Comment: The entries in the $X$ matrices are complex numbers. In the cases that I am familiar with (Sussking-type quantum Hall  models)  the $X^i$ are the  non-commuting coordinates so the dimension $d$ is the range $i=1,2,\ldots,d$. The number $N$ is  just a parameter. I have not looked at the Stringy examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help！I have read some articles about the large N limit.Does the N have some physical meaning?

Comment: Have you read https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0101029.pdf?

Comment: No, but I just had a quick look at it, and it does make the concept clear. This article might help me out. Thanks again for your help!